# copy recursively except hidden directory

Tags: linux, command-line, cp

How do I copy recursively like `cp -rf *`, but excluding hidden directories (directories starting with .) and their contents?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just copy everything with

```
cp -rf
```

and then delete hidden directories at the destination with

```
find -type d -name '.*' -and -not -name '.' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

Alternatively, if you have some advanced tar (e.g. GNU tar), you could try to use tar to exclude some patterns. But I am afraid that is not possible to only exclude hidden directories, but include hidden files.

For example something like this:

```
tar --exclude=PATTERN -f - -c * | tar -C destination -f - -x
```

Btw, GNU tar has a zoo of exclude style options. My favourite is

```
--exclude-vcs
```

Answer (score 33):

Good options for copying a directory tree except for some files are:

- **rsync**: this is basically cp plus a ton of exclusion possibilities.

  ```
  rsync -a --exclude='.*' /source/ /destination
  ```
- **pax**: it has some exclusion capabilities, and it's in POSIX so should be available everywhere (except that some Linux distributions don't include it in their default installation for some reason).

  ```
  cd /source && mkdir -p /destination && \
  pax -rw -pp -s '!.*/\..*!!'  . /destination
  ```

Answer (score 8):

alternatively to `cp` you could use `rsync` with an `--exclude=PATTERN`.